# Fedora 33 not booting into latest kernel

Tags: fedora, kernel, grub2, grub

[image]

Not the best picture (sorry), but every now and again whenever Fedora does an update, it appears to be adding a new line to my boot menu - the picture is old, I now have 3 versions of the kernal in the list now (kernel-5.8.15-301.fc33.x86_64, kernel-5.11.9-200.fc33.x86_64, kernel-5.11.11-200.fc33.x86_64).

The new line at the top does not load into a usable desktop or a login screen. It just goes to a blank screen with a cursor at the top left, no errors, messages or anything. Only Fedora 5.8.15 loads into a usable desktop.

How can I actually boot into the latest kernel version and remove the old ones?

Comment: Try this link https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/delete-remove-old-kernels-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having this problem, I believe it is because of the secure boot enabled. There is an open bug open with RedHat: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1724262

For now, running this command after a kernel update fixes the issue:

```
sudo grubby --update-kernel=ALL--args="dis_ucode_ldr"
```